# Making Terminal Opened File

Tags: command-line

I need to create a file if i double click it it will directly be opened by terminal. I wasn't able find info about that rather than clicking make file ex.. under properties section of a file. Can you guide me or mark this as duplicate of some other question?

Comment: What does the file contain? What do you expect will happen when the terminal "opens" this file?

Comment: @muru it contains a command 'cd /path/to/file ./program' executing it

Comment: make it an answer so i can accept it. Thank you m8!